# jUnit run certain test cases from different test classes each having multiple tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

How do I run certain selected test cases from different test classes each of which has multiple tests in it?

For example, I have 3 test classes TestClassA, TestClassB and TestClassC. Each of these test classes is having 3 tests.

```
public class TestClassA {
  @Test
  public void testA1() {
    //test method
  }

  @Test
  public void testA2() {
    //test method
  }

  @Test
  public void testA3() {
    //test method
  }
}


public class TestClassB {
  @Test
  public void testB1() {
    //test method
  }

  @Test
  public void testB2() {
    //test method
  }

  @Test
  public void testB3() {
    //test method
  }
}


public class TestClassC {
  @Test
  public void testC1() {
    //test method
  }

  @Test
  public void testC2() {
    //test method
  }

  @Test
  public void testC3() {
    //test method
  }
}
```

With reference to the above sample code, I would like to run tests testA1, testA2, testB2, testC2 and testC3 all at once. Is there any configuration for the same? Thank you

Comment: when you say "all at once" can you be more specific, please? Do you mean in parallel or one after the other in a specific order?

Comment: I mean all the tests in a single run just like running all the test cases from a class as we do in IntelliJ and jUnit configuration.